# implement checkbox or toggle switch in plugin code

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I need to implement a way to let the user decode a base64 string from the front-end. I want to add a toggle switch or a checkbox that if selected will encode or decode the input string. Is there a way to manage this on the backend of my plugin? I mean, if the user toggle the bs4 switch on or check the form control, the plugin will know what kind of operation do on the input text? any example will be appreciated
NB: I'm using a shortcode to render the HTML

bootstrap toggle switch

```
public function switch_form( array $attr, string $content = null ) : string
{
ob_start();
?>
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
```

bootstrap checkbox

```
public function switch_form( array $attr, string $content = null ) : string
{
ob_start();
?>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Toggle this custom radio</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Or toggle this other custom radio</label>
</div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Do you already have code that handles the form submit? (your own code? a form plugin?) It should be fairly easy to see the checkbox value there and either base64 decode your input or not.

Comment: Not at the moment, I will use ajax to manage the custom form I've made, As I know wordpress have a specific funtion to control checkbox?